# recursive DNS: do you ask for `A` at each level, or for `NS`?

Tags: dns, subdomain

How exactly is the DNS recursive resolution work:  when doing the recursion, at each level, do you ask the server for the record which you're trying to resolve (e.g. `l.p.example.net.`), with the type you're trying to resolve (e.g. `A` or `AAAA`), or do you actually ask who's responsible for the domain for which you're trying to find a record for?

For example, if some server is authoritative for domain `example.net.`, but is also recursive, and if `p.example.net.` is actually `NS` delegated to another, third-party server, would such third-party server actually receive any traffic, or would the recursive upper-level server not make such possible by already providing the resolutions for everything under its original authority?

Answer (score 0):

Recursive resolver supposed to ask each time for the same record it is trying to resolve. If what needs to be resolved is **A**, then **A** query is sent to root servers, .com servers, etc.

If p.example.com delegated to a separate server, then in the example.com zone, should exist NS record for p.example.com. If such delegation NS record exists, example.com server knows that p.example.com delegated to another server, and when queried for p.example.com "A" record, will answer with **NS** records for p.example.com.

That does not matter wheather example.com server is also recursive or not.